# Netlogo file-write/file-print/file-type outputs incomplete file

Tags: netlogo, large-files

At the conclusion of a netlogo run I would like to output 520 run-specific variables. I have used file-write to do so. But, when I do so, the output file(s) created are incomplete. For example, if I conduct 1,008 runs, results from only 734.xxx runs are written to the file. Here's the code for the file-write commands:

```
 file-open
    "Part01Results.txt"
   file-write actualcombo
   file-write parmcombo
   file-write xqa1
   file-write xqa2
   file-write xqa3
   file-write yqa1
   file-write yqa2
   file-write yqa3
   file-write zqa1
   file-write zqa2
   file-write zqa3
   file-write aqa1
   file-write aqa2
   file-write aqa3
   file-write bqa1
   file-write bqa2
   file-write bqa3
   file-write cqa1
   file-write cqa2
   file-write cqa3
   file-write ptotBP
   file-write ptotNBP
   file-write ptotNone
   file-write ptotDout
   file-write ototBP
   file-write ototNBP
   file-write ototNone
   file-write ototDout
   file-write utotBP
   file-write utotNBP
   file-write utotNone
   file-write utotDout
   file-write pmidit3
   file-write pmidit2
   file-write pmidit1
   file-write pmidit0
   file-write omidit3
   file-write omidit2
   file-write omidit1
   file-write omidit0
   file-write umidit3
   file-write umidit2
   file-write umidit1
   file-write umidit0
   file-write pcounterBP
   file-write pcounterNBP
   file-write pcounterNone
   file-write pcounterDout
   file-write ocounterBP
   file-write ocounterNBP
   file-write ocounterNone
   file-write ocounterDout
   file-write ucounterBP
   file-write ucounterNBP
   file-write ucounterNone
   file-write ucounterDout
   file-write pc440tot
   file-write pc430tot
   file-write pc420tot
   file-write pc410tot
   file-write ppm440MeanHgt
   file-write ppm440LowHgt
   file-write ppm440HiHgt
   file-write ppm430MeanHgt
   file-write ppm430LowHgt
   file-write ppm430HiHgt
   file-write ppm420MeanHgt
   file-write ppm420LowHgt
   file-write ppm420HiHgt
   file-write ppm410MeanHgt
   file-write ppm410LowHgt
   file-write ppm410HiHgt
   file-write ppm340MeanHgt
   file-write ppm340LowHgt
   file-write ppm340HiHgt
   file-write ppm330MeanHgt
   file-write ppm330LowHgt
   file-write ppm330HiHgt
   file-write ppm320MeanHgt
   file-write ppm320LowHgt
   file-write ppm320HiHgt
   file-write ppm310MeanHgt
   file-write ppm310LowHgt
   file-write ppm310HiHgt
   file-write ppm240MeanHgt
   file-write ppm240LowHgt
   file-write ppm240HiHgt
   file-write ppm230MeanHgt
   file-write ppm230LowHgt
   file-write ppm230HiHgt
   file-write ppm220MeanHgt
   file-write ppm220LowHgt
   file-write ppm220HiHgt
   file-write ppm210MeanHgt
   file-write ppm210LowHgt
   file-write ppm210HiHgt
   file-write ppm140MeanHgt
   file-write ppm140LowHgt
   file-write ppm140HiHgt
   file-write ppm130MeanHgt
   file-write ppm130LowHgt
   file-write ppm130HiHgt
   file-write ppm120MeanHgt
   file-write ppm120LowHgt
   file-write ppm120HiHgt
   file-write ppm110MeanHgt
   file-write ppm110LowHgt
   file-write ppm110HiHgt
   file-write opm440MeanHgt
   file-write opm440LowHgt
   file-write opm440HiHgt
   file-write opm430MeanHgt
   file-write opm430LowHgt
   file-write opm430HiHgt
   file-write opm420MeanHgt
   file-write opm420LowHgt
   file-write opm420HiHgt
   file-write opm410MeanHgt
   file-write opm410LowHgt
   file-write opm410HiHgt
   file-write opm340MeanHgt
   file-write opm340LowHgt
   file-write opm340HiHgt
   file-write opm330MeanHgt
   file-write opm330LowHgt
   file-write opm330HiHgt
   file-write opm320MeanHgt
   file-write opm320LowHgt
   file-write opm320HiHgt
   file-write opm310MeanHgt
   file-write opm310LowHgt
   file-write opm310HiHgt
   file-write opm240MeanHgt
   file-write opm240LowHgt
   file-write opm240HiHgt
   file-write opm230MeanHgt
   file-write opm230LowHgt
   file-write opm230HiHgt
   file-write opm220MeanHgt
   file-write opm220LowHgt
   file-write opm220HiHgt
   file-write opm210MeanHgt
   file-write opm210LowHgt
   file-write opm210HiHgt
   file-write opm140MeanHgt
   file-write opm140LowHgt
   file-write opm140HiHgt
   file-write opm130MeanHgt
   file-write opm130LowHgt
   file-write opm130HiHgt
   file-write opm120MeanHgt
   file-write opm120LowHgt
   file-write opm120HiHgt
   file-write opm110MeanHgt
   file-write opm110LowHgt
   file-write opm110HiHgt
   file-write upm440MeanHgt
   file-write upm440LowHgt
   file-write upm440HiHgt
   file-write upm430MeanHgt
   file-write upm430LowHgt
   file-write upm430HiHgt
   file-write upm420MeanHgt
   file-write upm420LowHgt
   file-write upm420HiHgt
   file-write upm410MeanHgt
   file-write upm410LowHgt
   file-write upm410HiHgt
   file-write upm340MeanHgt
   file-write upm340LowHgt
   file-write upm340HiHgt
   file-close
```

Here are some of the things I have done:

1)I monitored memory usage on my machine while the job ran. I observed no situation where memory seemed insufficient. But, I considered increasing Netlogo's access to memory, and have found ways to do so. But, I'd rather not monkey around with those deep commands without some clear knowledge that that is the problem. Hence, I did several additional things first.

2)Half of the variables are floats between -1 and 1. I reduced their precision to 5 digits to the right of the decimal.

3)Instead of writing one file of 520 variables I tried writing subsets of the variables to different files (with a key to match). Smaller files still have the problem. But even my small files had lines longer than 80 characters. Is that the problem? To make all files have less than 80 characters per line I would need at least 18 files. This is possible to implement, but I'd rather know that's the problem before I implement this response.

4)I dropped "file-flush" at various places of the file (in case I was facing an unobserved memory problem).

5)I dropped 'file-write "\n"' commands throughout the file (in case the lines were too long).

6)I switched everything to file-print in case I was using the wrong "file-*" command.

7)I quintuple checked whether the files were actually the correct length and my reading into the statistical package was flawed. But, as I simply block and copy the list of file-write commands into the package and delete the "file-write" language, this is not the basis of file-error. The file is actually truncated.

8)I dropped "file-print """ commands after every file-write command to input a separate line, in case variables were writing over each other (they were, prior to my truncating the floats).

I have attempted to run the model 1,008 times, each time setting some global parameters differently. The aim is to be able to sample across the space of valid global parameters. However, I cannot use Behavior Space because the global parameters are not independent and treating them as independent produces septillions of possibilities, only a minuscule fraction of which are actually valid combinations. Thus, using Behavior Space would at minimum waste lots of time and computing cycles; more likely, using Behavior Space would make it impossible to conduct the study owing to the low incidence of valid runs. Thus, instead, I have identified the valid combinations of global parameters, and seek to run some subset of them, get the output produced, and then analyze the results. Thus, I need some way to output the 520 variables that summarize the results.

I appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Answer (score 3):

I usually call `file-close` after each write to the file. I can't offer you a good technical reason why it would work, and I know it's not a particularly satisfying solution, but on the few occasions when I've had I/O problems, it's usually solved it. To save yourself the trouble of copy/pasting `file-close` 519 times, see if you can generate a list of all of them, and do a

```
foreach list-with-var-names [
  file-open "results.txt"
  file-write ?
  file-close
]
```

FWIW, when logging students' work in NetLogo I've written 10MB+ files with `file-write`, so writing 520 lines with each one variable should absolutely not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Arthur Hjorth! This works. I appreciate it. A downside is that each run had been 1.15 seconds, but now each run is 3.94 seconds. That more than tripling of runtime cuts the number of runs per day from about 74k to about 21k. That's consequential, for it makes the series of runs I need to complete take not 6 months but over 18 months--just because I have to open and close the file 520 times per run. Thus, I appreciate this fix, I really do, for without it I could do nothing. I will use it for now. But, I'm still on the lookout for a less time-consuming solution.